# when function's internal [[scope]] property is assigned?

Tags: javascript

just to clear my mind, correct me if i'm wrong. ok, let take this example:

```
function foo() {
    var x = 1;
    return function bar() {
        console.log(x);
    };
}

var b = foo();
b();
```

when `foo` is being executed code by code, and the control flow comes to `function bar()`, based on my understanding, this is the moment that `bar.[[scope]]` is assigned. `foo`'s scopeChain in execution context is copied to `bar.[[scope]]` which is a collection of `foo`'s active object (lexical environment from per ecma5) and it's ancestor's active object if any (global here)

is there any misunderstanding here?

Comment: Not really, the variable `x` is just available in any scope below it, including inside `bar()`. The context of the function depends on how it's called, not what it contains.

Comment: @adeneo–the context is established by how the code is written. How do you change an execution context by the call? Perhaps you mean *this*, which is one parameter of a function's execution context. ;-)

Comment: @adeneo, im not talking about the context and `this`, im talking about the scope chain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, `bar`'s `[[scope]]` is assigned when the function is created; it's Step 9 in [§13.2 *("Creating Function Objects")*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13.2).

You're correct that in this case, `bar` is created when, in the step-by-step order of the code, you reach

```
return function bar() {
```

...because you're using a named function expression. (If it were a function declaration, it wouldn't be in the step-by-step code, but that's another matter.)

`bar`'s `[[scope]]` is set to the lexical environment that's active as of when/where `bar` is created. In your code, that's the lexical environment as of the function expression, which is also the same as the variable environment for the current call to `foo` (because there's been no funny business like `with`) This is covered by [§13](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13) where it discusses the production

*FunctionExpression* : `function` *Identifier* `(` *FormalParameterListopt* `)` `{` *FunctionBody* `}`

Comment: so what if i just declared bar funciton before return it?

Comment: Assuming the declaration is within `foo` (and it would have to be, for the `x` thing to work), `[[scope]]` would be the same, it's just that the function would be created upon entry into `foo`, *before* the step-by-step execution of the code in `foo`. In your case, that would mean `bar` was created before `x` was assigned the value `1`. For that code, that doesn't matter, because nothing tries to *use* `x` before it gets `1` assigned to it (`bar` doesn't *use* `x` until you call it).

Comment: ok you are talking about `creation stage` and `execution stage`. do you mean in `creation stage`, `bar` is created with `[[scope]]` set to variable environment? but variable environment is never changed, is lexical environment you would like to point here?

Comment: @elaijuh: I don't understand the question. `[[scope]]` is assigned when a function is *created*. In this case, `bar` is *created* when `foo` is *called*` (and a new `bar` is created every time `foo` is called). `[[scope]]` is set to the current lexical environment as of where/when the function is created (sorry, yes, "lexical", not "variable"). I suggest reading the linked sections of the spec thoroughly. While the writing is...awkward...it's still possible to understand. (The ES6 spec, on the other hand, is Truly Awful.)

Comment: yeah, point 9 of the spec `Set the [[Scope]] internal property of F to the value of Scope.` and `a Lexical Environment specified by Scope` makes it clear that when function is created with it's `[[scope]]` adhere to `LexicalEnvironment`